# Encountered error when I try to run a class: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. JAR

Tags: java

I am a new beginner of Java. I wrote a Hello.java file **with a extend jar package "algs4.jar"**(my textbook asked me to use their own output/input library(Algorithm 4th Edition)), which can print a 'Hello,World!\n' string on the shell when executed. 
It was compiled without any error, *(command:javac -cp E:\AlgorithmExercise\lib\algs4.jar E:\AlgorithmExercise\codes\Hello\Hello.java)*
but when I tried to run the class (command: java codes.Hello.Hello), I got this error.

I guessed the reason of this error is because I forgot to enter the path of the algs4.jar package. so I modified the command: *java -cp .;E:\AlgorithmExercise\lib\algs4.jar codes.Hello.Hello*, but the terminal informed me that  it "cannot find or load the main class."

I am absolutely cannot understand what's going on, my classpath has no mistake on configure.

Comment: need code, please give

Comment: `java codes.Hello.Hello.java` should be `java -cp E:\AlgorithmExercise\lib\algs4.jar codes.Hello.Hello`

Comment: You must run ` java -cp .;E:\AlgorithmExercise\lib\algs4.jar codes.Hello.Hello` from the base directory while Hello.java is in the relative directory `codes\Hello`. In other words you must be in `E:\AlgorithmExercise`.

Comment: ahh, i made a mistake. it does  java codes.Hello.Hello